# Get max ID value with Entity Framework in C#

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

With the following JSON I want to get the max value of the email ID.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "Bill",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "emails": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "email": "jack@jackkkfgfkfgkkkkkk.com",
        "dateCreated": "2017-05-14T14:04:12.3299297-07:00"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "email": "jack@jackkkfkkkkkk.com",
        "dateCreated": "2017-05-14T14:04:24.1534621-07:00"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "email": "jack@jackfkkkkkk.com",
        "dateCreated": "2017-05-14T14:04:29.8526171-07:00"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "firstName": "Bill",
    "lastName": "Smith",
    "emails": [         
      {
        "id": 4,
        "email": "jack@jkkkkk.com",
        "dateCreated": "2017-05-14T14:04:45.8674213-07:00"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My code so far

```
var maxId = People.Select(p => p.Emails.Max(i => i.Id)).FirstOrDefault();
```

This however always returns 4, because it only check the first element. Is there a way to check all in a single linq statement? So the next value would be 5.

Comment: you should order your selected values before just taking the first of the returned elements.

Comment: With the code you posted I get 3, not 4.

Comment: `People.Select(p => p.Emails.Max(i => i.Id)).Max();` works for me

Answer (score 1):

You want the Max Id of all the emails.

```
var maxId = People.SelectMany(p => p.Emails).Max(e => e.Id);
var nextId = maxId++;
```

Use `SelectMany` to flatten all the emails into one sequence and then get the `Max` Id from that list.